# Trouble getting ResourceBundle to find bundle. How can I debug this?

Tags: java, debugging, resourcebundle

I'm having trouble getting ResourceBundle to 'find' my .properties files.  This is in a Java library project, and I'm hitting the error in my unit tests

> java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name ../strings, locale en_US
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
>       at com.company.sdk.java.resources.StringResources.(StringResources.java:23)
>       at com.company.sdk.java.resources.StringResources.getInstance(StringResources.java:34)
>       at com.company.sdk.java.resources.StringResources.getResource(StringResources.java:28)
>       at com.company.sdk.java.Tests.StringResourcesTest.testGetResources(StringResourcesTest.java:13)

Online I found that ResourceBundle looks in the classpath to find these files by default.

So I set a break point and ran this command to find it:

> getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()

and got this result:

> /Users/geoff/IdeaProjects/SDKparentFolder/CompanyJavaSDK/build/classes/main/

Now, my resources folder is under main, like so: 
main/resources/strings.properties

So I think I should be able to get the resources file by making a call like this:

> ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources/strings")

But I still get the same exception.  I think I must be missing something basic.  Anyone have a tip on how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Update: this is my directory structure.

```
[src]
  [main]
    [java] <- this folder is the 'generated source root in intellij
      [com]
        [company]
    [resources]
      (strings.properties)
```

I tried to address the strings.properties file by setting my bundle name to "resources.strings" but I got the same error.  I also tried putting them under the [java] generated source route, but it does not seem to help.  I am now using dot.separated.path names as recommended. 
I have also tried moving it under com.company.sdk.java.resources  but it still cannot find the file.

Answer (score 0):

The resource bundle name must contain dots, not slashes.  This is because a ResourceBundle can be either a class (that you write yourself, to define the necessary strings in some manner of your own), or it can be "manufactured" on the fly as a PropertyResourceBundle.

It would be helpful for you to read the exact search description here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader)

Also, be sure that the name you pass is relative to the root of your classpath.  It looks like it would be `com.company.sdk.java.resources.strings` but I can't be certain from what you've posted.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jerry, but I'm still hitting the same problem.  Does the 'classpath' in my question seem right to you?  Also, I've added info to the end of the question.  Thanks,

Comment: Oops.  Sorry, Jeff; just noticed this question.  Anyway, no; under resources, make a structure similar to the Java code.  Maven (which I assume that you're using from this structure) will push all of that stuff into the generated .jar, .war or whatever.  So your properties file should end up under com.company, and would thus be "com.company.strings".